# Autofill cells in a column based on the non blank cells in a different column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to fill blank cells in column A corresponding to the non blank cells in column B. Below is the current state.

```
Fields  ISIN
ABC     ABC12345
        ABC12346
        ABC12347
        ABC12348
        ABC12349
        ABC12350
        ABC12351
        ABC12352
```

My desired state is to auto fill the blank cells in Column A (Fields) till nonblank cells in column B(ISIN)

```
Fields  ISIN
ABC     ABC12345
ABC     ABC12346
ABC     ABC12347
ABC     ABC12348
ABC     ABC12349
ABC     ABC12350
ABC     ABC12351
ABC     ABC12352
```

Comment: `=LEFT(B1;3)` and pull down? Why do you need VBA?

Comment: Hey prextor...ABC was used as an example, it can be any other value as well. I need VBA as I need to iterate this multiple times based on a copied value from different sheet.

Comment: Well, the code using VBA would be the same:
`Left(your_string_variable, 3)` and store the result into a String variable. See documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/left-function